# Difference between GPEDIT, RSOP, SECPOL, AD policies

Tags: windows

When I open Group policy Editor/Group Policy Object Editor, Local Security Settings (SECPOL), Reluctant Set of Policy (RSOP), or Active directory Users and Computers > Domain > Properties > Policies > Edit policy. They all look the same, so what exactually is the difference between them?

I know that SECPOL is just half of what is shown in gpedit, but all of the actual policies and hives look identical everywhere.

MMC can use these snapins for local or remote computers too, and can do this between a DOMAIN or a WORKGROUP, by clicking 'This snapin will manage' > 'network computer' > 'Select Computer' > 'Locations'.